# sed with variables containing /

Tags: linux, sed, variable, replace

i have a text file containing some content like that,

```
some content  
replace content  
other content
```

and i have some variables, looking like this:

```
PATH="/path/to/scriptdir"
PARAMETERS="para1 para2"
FILETOCHANGE="/foo/bar"
```

Now i want to replace the content in the text file that begins with *replace*, with the content of the variables *PATH* and *PARAMETERS*. The text file should look like that, after the replace:

```
some content
/path/to/scriptdir/script para1 para2
other content
```

I just tried the a couple of sed commands, but always i get an error. For example

```
sed -i "s/^replace.*$/$PATH/script $PARAMETERS/g" $FILETOCHANGE
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'
```

or

```
sed -i "s|^replace.*$|$PATH/script $PARAMETERS|g" $FILETOCHANGE
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unterminated `s' command
```

Can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Note that `$PATH` is a special variable that contains paths to executable files, use `$path` isntead.

Comment: Your first attempt fails because the replacement ("$PATH") contains additional `/` characters.  But your second should work, and with the values of `PATH` and `PARAMETERS` you've given, the resulting command should be less than 58 characters.  Please can you confirm the actual values of these variables?

Comment: I confirm that using pipe `|` instead of backslash works. The issue is probably due to the fact that `$PATH` does not contain what you think.

Comment: @JigglyNaga  I think you are right. I did some tests. My list of parameters is long. One parameter looks like `/data/data/dir/more/scriptname` and i have usually four parameters. I tested the command only with one parameter and it works. Do you know what i have to do, that my command can have more characters or do i have to split my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution is to switch from sed to Perl which handles variables as first class citizens, not as macros to expand as the shell does.

```
path=/path/to/scriptdir parameters="para1 para2" perl -i~ -pe \
    's|^replace.*$|$ENV{path}/script $ENV{parameters}|g' -- "$filetochange"
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing it
- the `%ENV` hash contains the environment variables, assigning to them at the beginning of a command makes them exported for the command
- `s///` (change the delimiters as you wish) works similarly to sed, see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)

Comment: Thanks that works. I did some tests and i think now i know what that problem in my sed command was (see my comment above to JigglyNaga). With the perl code i don't have such limitations, that i have with my sed command and the long argument list.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Do **not** use the variable `PATH` for this. It has a special meaning for the shell. I choose `SCRIPTDIR` here:

```
SCRIPTDIR="/path/to/scriptdir"
PARAMETERS="para1 para2"
FILETOCHANGE="/foo/bar"
```

(2) You do not need a slash (`/`) per se in sed's substitution command: `s#this#that#` or `s|this|that|` works as well as `s/this/that/g`. Sed just uses the character directly after the `s` as the separator for the rest of the `s` (substitute) command. You can use this to avoid the problem with the slashes in your pattern and replacement string: when you use e.g. `|` as a seperator, the slashes do not have any special meaning for sed.

So, this will work:

```
sed "s%^replace.*$%$SCRIPTDIR/script $PARAMETERS%g" $FILETOCHANGE
```

Comment: Your answer shall be validated as answer instead of the other one. Thanks !